# Conditional operator OR not working with custom fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop, query-posts

OR operator is not working for both conditions, only check first value if true then code executed and if first is false then not check 2nd condition and return else output.

I also try with **LIKE** compare, but then it's check custom fields value with all other values and if This CF value's contain by any other string CF value then it's become true.

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 14,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'travel',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
            'key'   => 'Swimming',
            'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Swimming',true),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
      array(
            'key'   => 'Boat', 
            'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Boat',true),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ))));
        if($posts) { 
             foreach($posts as $post) {
?>
 <?php the_title(); ?> 
    <?php 
    }  
}
else { 
?>  
<?php echo "No Update";
}
?>
```

Comment: For a meta query your `value` should just be the value you're looking for - i.e. change the `get_post_meta()` calls to just `Swimming` and `Boat`. See if that helps.

Comment: Note that this would be _much_ faster if it was a taxonomy with a `swimming` and a `boat` term, `meta_query` is slow and doesn't scale well as the site gets larger. Post meta tables were designed for fetching data when you already know the post you want, it was never intended for searches like this. That's what taxonomy tables and `tax_query` is for. If you need to store data put it in post meta, but if you need to search/find/filter/query for data on a post that isn't in its main content/title, put it in a taxonomy

Comment: Also, `get_posts` is slower than `WP_Query` as it's uncached, you need to add the `suppress_filters` parameter and set it to `false` so that caching plugins and filters can speed it up

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used `OR`, specifically the human verbal colloquial understanding, not the logical definition. *What you actually meant was `AND`.*

Here's a table demonstrating what happens to A and B for each comparison:

| `A` | `B` | `AND` | `OR` | `XOR` | `===` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ |
| true | true | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| false | true | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |
| true | false | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |

- `OR` means if *any* of the values are true, e.g. if one is false and the other is true
- `XOR` means if one of the values is true *( but not both at the same time )*
- `AND` means if all/both of the values are true, and none are false
- `==`means if both of the values are equivalent e.g. `true` and `"true"` are equivalent
- `===`/`EQUAL` means if both of the values are *exactly* the same